# Return x number of rows above VLOOKUP()

Tags: excel

I am using a vlookup to find the last non-empty cell in a column. What I need to do now is find x number of rows above that. I am using this formula:

`=INDIRECT(LOOKUP(2,1/(Sheet2!A:A<>""),Sheet2!A:A) & ROW() - 1)`

I was hoping this would return the value in the cell above the last non-empty cell in the column. However, it just gives me a #REF error. I have attempted to Google the solution but cannot seem to find anything. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are those cells numbers or text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the value of the row above the last use one of these two formulas:

If the column is text use this:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH("ZZZ",Sheet2!A:A)-1)
```

If it is numeric then use this:

```
=INDEX(Sheet2!A:A,MATCH(1e+99,Sheet2!A:A)-1)
```

Where the `-1` is the number of rows up from the last row desired.

Comment: Worked like a charm! It was text so I used the first formula. You rock, Scott. Thank you!